# mapping automatically columns into a destination flat file in SSIS

Tags: ssis, mapping, flat-file

I need to export a table having more than 100  colonnes to a destination flat file, how can I map them automatically and not one by one one  manually     in SSIS SQL2012.  There is any option as the automatic mapping existing in  DTS?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the flat file already exists,  then it's a simple matter of going into your flat file destination and there should be an  option,  might be right click, for auto map by column name.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your text file has column names specified in it, it will be named column1 to column100. This will not automatically map to your destination (Unless destination is column1 to column100). You will have to put in the effort and rename the 'column1' names of the text source to your destination's column names.